# Why do I still have optparse being used in Django v1.7.4?

Tags: python, django, argparse, optparse

`argparse` is the tool Django (allegedly) uses for parsing the command line, as per [this commit](https://github.com/django/django/commit/f17b24e407385eb18651bf023a187347aa9c1f75) and [this support ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19973).

However, nine months have passed now, and when I visit the `BaseCommand` declaration I see:

```
from optparse import make_option, OptionParser

...

option_list = (
    make_option('-v', '--verbosity', action='store', dest='verbosity', default='1',
        type='choice', choices=['0', '1', '2', '3'],
        help='Verbosity level; 0=minimal output, 1=normal output, 2=verbose output, 3=very verbose output'),
    make_option('--settings',
        help='The Python path to a settings module, e.g. "myproject.settings.main". If this isn\'t provided, the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable will be used.'),
    make_option('--pythonpath',
        help='A directory to add to the Python path, e.g. "/home/djangoprojects/myproject".'),
    make_option('--traceback', action='store_true',
        help='Raise on exception'),
    make_option('--no-color', action='store_true', dest='no_color', default=False,
        help="Don't colorize the command output."),
)
```

When will Django use `argparse` in 1.7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commit you link to is tagged for v1.8b2. Looking at the source code for the stable [v1.7.x](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.7.x/django/core/management/base.py) and [v1.8.x](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.8.x/django/core/management/base.py) branches it looks like `argparse` will be introduced as the default in v1.8. See also the [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.8/#management-commands-that-only-accept-positional-arguments) for v1.8.

However, `optparse` will remain as a fallback option (to allow continued support for Python versions prior to 2.7/3.2) until Django v2. According to the [test source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/197dd4b8f12164f6acebb3b959f9ac2040a40400/tests/user_commands/tests.py#L110):

> `optparse` should be supported during Django 1.8/1.9 releases

Comment: Damn it -.-'' you're right. Did not check the whole source code, and thought it was for 1.7. I can think about a lof of manage.py commands in 3rd party apps which will be broken in 1.8.

Comment: @LuisMasuelli true. As the release notes put it: *"You can make your command backwards compatible by simply setting the `args` class variable. However, if you don’t have to keep compatibility with older Django versions, it’s better to implement the new `add_arguments()` method as described in [Writing custom django-admin commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/)."*